# Python - local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python (please bear with me if its a silly error...)

I have a function which increments a global variable x every time it is called when the if-condition is not satisfied.

My function looks like this:

```
#x is declared here as a global variable
x = 0

def gen_pos(tag):
    if next(tag.iterancestors(),None)==None:
        x = 0
        y = 0
    else:
        #increment here
        x+= 1
        y = 0
        while tag is not None:
            y -= 1
            tag = tag.getparent()
    return zip(x,y)
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

The location of the error is in

```
x+=1
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reference x as global in the function using

```
global x
```

Your code will look like this,

```
x = 0
def gen_pos(tag):
    global x
    if next(tag.iterancestors(),None)==None:
        x = 0
        y = 0
    else:
        #increment here
        x+= 1
        y = 0
        while tag is not None:
            y -= 1
            tag = tag.getparent()
    return zip(x,y)
```

Comment: Also note that if `x` is not declared as a global variable, then the statement `x = 0` will create a local variable, which is distinct from the global one.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never useful for a function to modify a global variable. Doing so makes it difficult to track which functions can effect which variables. If you pass `x` as a parameter, it makes it much more clear which things effect which other things.

Also, `zip` arguments must be iterables. I assume you meant to return a tuple.

```
def gen_pos(tag, x):
    if next(tag.iterancestors(),None)==None:
        return 0, 0
    y = 0
    while tag is not None:
        y -= 1
        tag = tag.getparent()
    return x + 1, y
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare that you use a global variable

```
#x is declared here as a global variable
x = 0

def gen_pos(tag):
    global x
```

You can read more about this problem in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python